# Create new file and read it using NSFileManager objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, nsfilemanager

question: I want to write to a new file some data that I already have into a NSMutableData .

I was reading in several places about this but it's not clear at all. 
I was coding the next and It does not crash but I don´t know how to manipulate the "new file" since I don't know how to read it.

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewDataFile.txt"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:dataPath contents:dataBuffer attributes:nil];
```

Can someone complement this code or explain how to handle new files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next link explain very well how to handle a file, it helped me a lot.

http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/using-the-document-directory-to-store-files

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to read a file.  Use NSFileHandle to open the file and read from it, or use something like NSData's dataWithContentsOfFile: or dataWithContentsOfURL:.

Comment: Hi @Nicholas, quick question, when I write the next: 
    NSString* dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewDataFile.txt"];

Does this create a new file called NewDataFile.txt?

Comment: stringByAppendingPathComponent: appends the string "NewDataFile.txt" to your documentsDirectory string and inserts a path separator ("/") if necessary, then returns the resulting string.  NSFileManager's createFileAtPath: is what creates the file.

Comment: ok at the end I have a new file called NewDaaFile.txt who can be handle by NSFileHandle Class right?